# ws4py appears a error in Linux system

Tags: python, linux, websocket, ws4py, wsgiserver

I use ws4py as a websocket server. it can run normally in Windows and Mac, but it runs in linux system raising a TB when websocket clients connect to server. Anybody can tell me how to fix this bug?

```
[2016-01-06 20:51:43,094] ERROR Failed to receive data
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/yzliu/airtest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ws4py/websocket.py", line 300, in once
    b = self.sock.recv(self.reading_buffer_size)
File "/home/yzliu/airtest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/_socket2.py", line 264, in recv
    return sock.recv(*args)
File "/home/yzliu/airtest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/_socket2.py", line 73, in _dummy
raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
```

Comment: Sample code? Please.

Comment: def start_ws4py_server():
    server = WSGIServer(('', 9002), WebSocketWSGIApplication(handler_cls=WebSocket_Handler))
    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    configure_logger()
    start_ws4py_server()

Comment: No man, modify/edit the post and include the code in there. Indented please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ws4py, when used with gevent 1.1, as the underlying
socket is closed when WSGI handler returns.

See: https://github.com/Lawouach/WebSocket-for-Python/pull/180/files

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes